# AngularJS getting the input value to store in $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
<input id="width" name="width" style="width:100px" value="550" type="text" ng-model="width">
```

How would I get the value from above to write into the $scope under `$scope.user.width` ?

Whilst keeping the initial `value="500"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialise the value in your controller:

```js
$scope.user = {width : 500};
```

```html
<input id="width" name="width" type="text" ng-model="user.width">
```

Comment: `$scope.user.width` would update with the value when the input field value has changed?

Comment: Of course! That's the goal of the [`ngModel` directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel).

Comment: Does `$scope.user.width` or `$scope.user = {width: ''};` need to be set in order for `<input id="width" name="width" type="text" ng-model="user.width">` to store the values?

Comment: @Donald It will be set automatically when the input value is changed if not defined previously, if this is your question.